# Cant get relations: searching Products from Category (typeorm)

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to list the products from an especific category. However it doesnt return anything. There is no errors, and the category has two products on DB.

Here is the GET method:

```
categoriesRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params;
  const categoryRepository = getRepository(Category);
  const category = await categoryRepository.findOne(id);
  console.log(category);
  const categoryProducts = category?.products;
  return response.json(categoryProducts);
});
```

And the relations:

Category model:

```
  @OneToMany(type => Product, category => Category)
  products: Product[];
```

Product model:

```
  @ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.products, { eager: true })
  category: Category;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coudnt figure out how to solve this, so I decided to use de id and make a query:

```
categoriesRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params;
  const productRepository = getRepository(Product);
  const categoryProducts = await productRepository.find({
    where: { category: id },
  });

  return response.json(categoryProducts);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the product relation needs to be loaded with the categoryentity:

```
    categoriesRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params;
  const categoryRepository = getRepository(Category);
  const category = await categoryRepository.findOne(id,{relations:['products']}); // add relations 
  console.log(category);
  const categoryProducts = category?.products;
  return response.json(categoryProducts);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunelly it didn't work. The server throws an error "Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined".